# How to write duplicate error in action_confirm button in openerp

Tags: odoo

```
def action_confirm(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """ Confirms procurement and writes exception message if any.
    @return: True
    """
    move_obj = self.pool.get('stock.move')

    for procurement in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        data=procurement.product_id.id
        pro_list.append(data)
        if procurement.product_qty <= 0.00:
            raise osv.except_osv(_('Data Insufficient!'),
                _('Please check the quantity in procurement order(s) for the '
                  'product "%s", it should not be 0 or less!' %
                   procurement.product_id.name))

        if procurement.product_id.type in ('product', 'consu'):
            if not procurement.move_id:
                source = procurement.location_id.id
                if procurement.procure_method == 'make_to_order':
                    source = procurement.product_id.property_stock_procurement.id
                id = move_obj.create(cr, uid, {
                    'name': procurement.name,
                    'location_id': source,
                    'location_dest_id': procurement.location_id.id,
                    'product_id': procurement.product_id.id,
                    'product_qty': procurement.product_qty,
                    'product_uom': procurement.product_uom.id,
                    'date_expected': procurement.date_planned,
                    'state': 'draft',
                    'company_id': procurement.company_id.id,
                    'auto_validate': True,
                })
                move_obj.action_confirm(cr, uid, [id], context=context)
                self.write(cr, uid, [procurement.id], {'move_id': id, 'close_move': 1})
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': 'confirmed', 'message': ''})

    return True
```

Comment: Need more explanation of problem.  What's the second error?  How do you notice it?  Or do you mean you want an error if someone tries to do the same move twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

def action_confirm(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

```
    move_obj = self.pool.get('stock.move')

    for procurement in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context): 


        cr.execute("select id,order_id,foc from sale_order_line where product_id = %s and order_id= %s and foc = %s", (procurement.product_id.id, procurement.move_id.sale_line_id.order_id.id, procurement.foc,))
        data = cr.fetchall()
        count = len(data)                     

        if count >= 2:
            raise osv.except_osv(_('Data Duplicate!'),
                                      _('Please check the sale order line.Duplicate record can not allow.'))
        else:
            {}
        if procurement.product_qty <= 0.00:
            raise osv.except_osv(_('Data Insufficient!'),
                _('Please check the quantity in procurement order(s) for the product "%s", it should not be 0 or less!' % procurement.product_id.name))

        if procurement.product_id.type in ('product', 'consu'):
            if not procurement.move_id:
                source = procurement.location_id.id
                if procurement.procure_method == 'make_to_order':
                    source = procurement.product_id.property_stock_procurement.id
                id = move_obj.create(cr, uid, {
                    'name': procurement.name,
                    'location_id': source,
                    'location_dest_id': procurement.location_id.id,
                    'product_id': procurement.product_id.id,
                    'product_qty': procurement.product_qty,
                    'foc':procurement.foc,
                    'product_uom': procurement.product_uom.id,
                    'date_expected': procurement.date_planned,
                    'state': 'draft',
                    'company_id': procurement.company_id.id,
                    'auto_validate': True,
                })
                move_obj.action_confirm(cr, uid, [id], context=context)
                self.write(cr, uid, [procurement.id], {'move_id': id, 'close_move': 1})               
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': 'confirmed', 'message': ''})

    return True
```

Comment: This answer is the best for me...So..I share you..to progess.